# Sculpting and keeping an image visible

Tags: blend-files, sculpting

I can add a background image and, for example, assign it to top or bottom, cut off half the box, mirror add my other modifiers but this is when the problems start.

If I try to sculpt, the image simply goes away.  I have to hit top and then orthographic again to get the image back.

I guess I could assign the image to the camera and do the same thing and it would stay there, right but why does the image go poof as soon as I grab a brush and try to do anything to surface I am going to start working with?

If anyone knows a tutorial that covers this, please let me know.  I have chased my own tail for 4 hours in YouTube and in the Blender.org community and not found an answer.

Thanks!

Richard

Comment: Background images can be used either in orthographic views or while viewing from camera.So you can add background image for Camera view, lock cmera to view and sculpt straight from there (it may be not convenient). *OR* you could add a plane with this image assigned to it as a texture, position it so it to be seen while in Camera view and parent it to camera.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using background images you can use an empty to place an image in the 3DView.

[image]

You then get a reference image that is always visible as you rotate around.

[image]

Comment: Absolutely excellent suggestion!  Thank you!  Richard.